# Insert Query Not working at a particular time of the day in VS 2015! Exact same time everyday

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2015

A Windows application using Winforms and SQL Server in VS 2015. Project works fine at all times except from 10:00AM to 1:00PM CST.

During this time of the day, every other query like `DELETE` / `UPDATE` works, but an `INSERT` query does not seem to insert any data into my table. I am using `ExecuteNonQuery()` to get my data inserted in my SQL table. This is a very strange problem and I do not get any error, my query works fine at other times.

Please help me if anyone has any idea! Thank you!

```
SqlConnection STDB = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename=C:\VS\MainProject\MainProject\STDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True");

STDB.Open();
DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save changes?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    string query10 = $"INSERT INTO [dbo].[Inbound](TrailerNo, ShipperNo, 
      SealNo, ReceivedBy, ReceivingShift, Carrier, Supplier, Vendor, 
      Contents, Location, Comments, Date, Time, Status) VALUES 
      ('{textBox1.Text}','{textBox2.Text}','{textBox3.Text}', 
       '{comboBox5.Text}','{comboBox1.Text}','{comboBox6.Text}',
       '{textBox4.Text}','{textBox5.Text}','{comboBox2.Text}',
       '{comboBox3.Text}','{TextBox6.Text}','{dateTimePicker1.Text}',
       '{dateTimePicker2.Text}','{textBox7.Text}')";

    SqlDataAdapter SDA30 = new SqlDataAdapter(query10, STDB);

    SDA30.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Information Saved!");
    clear();
}
else
{
     //do nothing
}

STDB.Close();
```

Comment: How is anyone realistically meant to guess why your code doesn't run between those hours!?

Comment: I am asking for a solution if anyone has encountered such a thing in past and might know the problem. @Equalsk

Comment: You said it fails to insert but you dont get any errors?

Comment: Yes @Coffeegrinder No Errors, the data just doesn't get inserted.

Comment: This is crazy-vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: Is there some scheduled task running at that time that might be doing something with the DB?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Yes I am aware of that I am just trying to get my query work will parameterize later! but thank you for your comment!

Comment: @juharr I am not really sure, fairly new to VS any idea how can I check if there is a scheduled task running?

Comment: Don't do it that way. Too often "parameterize later" becomes "parameterize never", and a year later you suddenly find out you were hacked six months ago.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn haha I gues syou are right..I will work on it! Thank you

Comment: Maybe "Mc'Intosh Shipping Co" arrives with a shipment every day at 10:00.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all the help. I caught the Error! The time column in the database was set to NVARCHAR(10) and so everyday at 10:00 AM -12:59 PM there was 1 character extra, I had a catch block so did not receive any exception but on step by step info, I got to know that there was an exception "String or binary data would be truncated."  I updated my Time column with NVARCHAR(50) in my data table and everything works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Task Scheduler and Event Logs to see what is going on during those times on the days in question.